# Using Typescript to map database schemas

Tags: typescript, database-schema

I have a legacy database which I want to expose over a fresh new API.

I need to map the field names of the models from the legacy db to my new model classes.

I want to do this in a type-safe way instead of using just a dictionary of string mappings which are prone to errors.

```
// The new model.
class Patient {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  dateOfBirth: Date
}

var p: Patient;

legacyToNewModelMappings =
  "First Name": p.firstName
  "Family Name": p.familyName
  "DOB": p.dateOfBirth
```

This is nice because if I change a field in my new model, refactoring will be easy and I will get an alert in my IDE if there is an issue.

However I need to be able to map back and forth between the two models. Using references though means I can't map from the legacy DB to the new DB.

I am using TypeScript in Node.js.

Any other approaches I should be looking at?

Comment: You mean back from new DB to legacy DB?  This is a JavaScript problem, not really related to TypeScript.  Your mapping needs to be two-way, but JavaScript object hashes are only one-way.  So you either have to build two mapping dictionaries in two directions, or use property search for one of the directions (probably the least used one).  Some JavaScript libraries contain a "reverse object" function that builds a new object, switching property keys with values -- in that case, you build one mapping, then "reverse" it to get the other direction.

Comment: Also, your legacyToNewModelMappings doesn't work.  This will build  your mapping with values that are the current values of the properties when you build the mapping object.  You typically build two functions, setLegacyToNewModel() and getLegacyFromNewModel() that contain switch statements on the property name if you don't want to use property name indexing on the TypeScript class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to understand what you try to accomplish here, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Couldn't you use getters and setters on one model to match the properties of field names for both databases?

```
class Patient {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public dateOfBirth: Date;

    get "First Name" (): string {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    get "Family Name" (): string {
        return this.familyName;
    }
    get "DOB" (): Date {
        return this.dateOfBirth;
    }

    set "First Name" (value: string) {
        this.firstName = value;
    }
    set "Family Name" (value: string) {
        this.familyName = value;
    }
    set "DOB" (value: Date) {
        this.dateOfBirth = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa thank you! I did not know about get and set syntax in Typescript. This looks great.